# PoE switch to power Cisco Aironet 1200 access points

Tags: cisco, access-point, power-over-ethernet

I have a draytek P2260 poe switch which can provide up to 15.4 watt of power to devices like IP phones. This switch is a 24-ports 802.3af PoE PSE
However Cisco Aironet AP require 18.5 watts and at the moment they are powered through an injector.

Just out of curiosity, how possible is it to combine the power of 2 ports to reach 18.5 Watt ?

Comment: I seriously doubt this is possible.

Comment: There are some small switches with PoE+, even 30W per port.

Comment: I just got a PoE+ capable switch by my 1252 ap still complains of reduced power input.... did you manage to get yours working properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not going to happen.

Keep the current setup with the injector or try a switch that can provide more PoE wattage ([PoE+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet)) to individual ports.